# Hide div with close button jquery only with associated div

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is what I am trying to do, close the notification bar if the x inside it is clicked.

Here is my code: http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/qK3yK/2/

```
    $('#closeButton').on('click', function(e) { 
        $('#previewBox').remove(); 
    });
```

How can I make it so it only closes the warning with which it is associated with, instead of removing all of them though. I'm sure the word "this" is needed in the code, but I can't understand where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use jquery [`.parent()`](https://api.jquery.com/parent/) to get the parent of each element in the current set of matched elements, optionally filtered by a selector. Try this:

```
$('#close').on('click', function(e) { 
   $(this).parent('.alert').remove(); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kunknown/qK3yK/3/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#closeButton").on('click', function() {
    $(this).parent().remove();
});
```

this will remove prev elemement.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. You have to get it is parent not that element itself

$('#closeButton').on('click', function(e) { 
        $(this).parent('.alert').remove(); 
    });

Or

```
 $('#closeButton').on('click', function(e) { 
        $(this).parent().remove(); 
    });
```

This will remove closest parent

Answer (score 1):

What i assume is that you are trying to remove the parent of the 'x'.
On clicking on `x` . The parent div should be removed.

Make these changes in your JS file

```
$('#closeButton').on('click', function(e) { 
  var par = $(e.target).parent();   
  $('par').remove(); 
});
```